# How can I use data members on a reference without creating an object with new keyword?

Tags: c++, class, new-operator

```
class player{
   public:
      int a;
}
int main(){
   player p1;
   p1.a=10;
}
```

I created a reference variable p1 of player but not the actual object on heap since I haven't used the new keyword on p1. But, c++ compiler allows me to assign value 10 to data member 'a' of p1. How is this possible without having an object on heap?

Comment: Because it is on the  stack aka local to the scope

Comment: I c++ you can create things on heap with `new` or create them on stack. That's what you are doing here. This is not java. Read more about it.

Comment: There are plenty of related question in the "Related" section, have a look.

Comment: If you really just want a pointer (and btw. 'Reference' is something different than 'Pointer' in C++), then you need to declare `p1` with `player* p1`.

Comment: `p1` is not a reference varaible.   This is C++, not Java.   They work differently.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question based on a false premise (that C++ and Java work in the same way, with a case where they explicitly differ).

Comment: How to use a variable is example 2 in my C++ book, right after the "Hello World!" example. Please read another page in *your* book.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question based on a false premise (that C++ and Java work in the same way, with a case where they explicitly differ).

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing C++ with Java. `p1` is not a reference, it's just an object with automatic storage duration. It's created when the variable's scope begins, and it's destroyed when the variable's scope ends.

In C++, you normally only use the "heap" (the correct word would be: the free store) if you need more complex control over an object's lifetime.

If you don't need this special control, then an object in C++ works just like, say, an `int` or a `double`. You wouldn't feel it's necessary to write `new int` or `new double`, would you? Well, in C++, your `player` acts like an `int` or a `double` in this regard. It's a major difference to almost all other popular programming languages.

Comment: thanks mate, you got me, I was confused between c++ and java. And I did a lot of research before asking the ques, so pls dont downvote it :(